# Passing tablename to a stored procedure c#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I'm new to programming and I'm programming with Visual Studio. I'm trying to get an input from user (a name of a site like google.com) and search for the site name toward my tables (I have different domain tables such as .com , .org , etc).

So, I'm trying to write this stored procedure which selects from a table without actual table name (I'm trying to pass table name from input to stored procedure) here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @link nvarchar(50)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM @link
```

I have defined `linksg` (set and get) like this:

```
public string linksg
{
    get { return link; }
    set { link = value; }
}
```

and this is how I defined `linksg` in a function (my `search_sitedomain` function takes a domain like .com and gives a link to a table which includes your sitename like .com table):

```
public void search_sitedomain()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SM;Initial Catalog=mohandesi-net;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("search_sitedomain", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@domain", domain);

    con.Open();
    string link = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    linksg = link;
    MessageBox.Show(link);
}
```

The `search_sitedomain` function works perfectly fine and returns the link but my stored procedure doesn't work like it can't replace `@link` with a tablename (like .com)

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't parameterize an object name, only a value.  You *could* dynamically build a string and execute that string as a SQL query.  But, more to the point, *why*?  Why are you storing the same data in multiple tables?  Put your "websites" in *one* table and just select from that.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the database design from what you have described, however you could use dynamic sql to execute this select statement, although this is not an ideal solution.  Is there a reason why you do not store the domain data in another table and then join them both based on what you need to get?

Comment: @David hi david . we have to use recursive DNS query , so I have to have a root table which is empty , and just leads to one of the domain tables

Comment: @DavidB hi david thanks for your reply . can you answer my question please if you know how to do this with dynamic sql? yes I explained the reason in first comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion having a parametrized table name is a huge security hole, but it's possible to do it as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
@link nvarchar(50)
AS
EXEC ('SELECT * FROM dbo.['+@link+']');
```

Comment: If you must, at least use [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql)